# Connection refused (error 111) when sending SMTP mail

Tags: email, godaddy

Have a site where when sending mail using an SMTP connect, I'm getting a "connection refused" error.

When sending email using PHP or Sendmail, site owner is not receiving the emails at all.

Site is hosted on GoDaddy... and can't be moved to new hosting company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to enable "Remote Mail Exchanger" setting in the MX Records section of the cPanel.

Once I did this, I was able to use PHP mail.

Comment: doesn't work for me and i am using remote mail exchange in my subdomine, some idea?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if there's something different when using a subdomain. I'd recommend giving GoDaddy support a call and asking.